# Rails can't find view template even though it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is the error I'm getting whenever I'm accessing localhost:3000/cats:

Missing template cats/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
* "/home/mikael/RubyOnRailsLearning/NinetyNineCats/app/views"
  * "/home/mikael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actiontext-6.0.2.1/app/views"
  * "/home/mikael/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionmailbox-6.0.2.1/app/views"

My view templates are located like so:

app/views-layouts/cats/index.html.erb, show.html.erb

I have also tried removing them from cats and into the views folder.

My index controller action is this:

```
def index
    @cats = Cat.all

    render :index
 end
```

The routes.rb file has only this inside:

```
resources :cats
```

This project worked fine yesterday. It could find the templates and render them just fine. But I wanted to restart it so I deleted the rails app folder without dropping the database and I remade it today. The database schema got uploaded into the rails app.

I can't think of anything that might be causing this problem besides me not dropping yesterday's database and not remaking it. (it's the only difference)

Comment: Did you post all of the error message?  `Missing template cats/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:` It looks like it was about to list the directories it was searching in which will help troubleshoot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that your view is in

```
app/views-layouts/cats/index.html.erb
```

but Ruby on Rails conventions expect it in

```
app/views/cats/index.html.erb
```

Comment: It's named "views/layouts" by default.

Comment: Rails expects layout files (like the `application` layout) in `app/views/layouts`, but view for actions (like `cat#index`) belong into `app/views/cats/index.html.erb`, not nested below the `layouts` folder.

Comment: You are right. My vscode file tree had "views/layouts" together and I accidentally made the templates inside layouts. Looking at my folders through the kubuntu file manager, I changed the location of the files.